# How to focus/click on YouTube's Comment Box with JS (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, youtube, browser-extension

### 1. Context

I'm creating a [browser extension to enhance YouTube's keyboard navigation](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/youtube_kbd_nav). One of the shortcuts I have in mind is for commenting<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1: I'm currently using Dart, but it mimics JS and later gets transpiled to it anyway.</sub>

### 2. What I've Tried

YouTube uses a lot of custom HTML elements, so it hasn't been clear to me what works and when, I end up having to reverse-engineer what's going on every time I'm faced with a custom tag.

I've basically tried mostly something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#labelAndInputContainer > div').click();
```

Should I use `focus()` instead?

The `div#labelAndInputContainer` element gets a new class called `focused` once it is focused.

### 3. Other Optional Challenge

> The discussion of this last section has been redirected to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63875009/4756173).

At first, YouTube doesn't load the comment section below a video. Only when you scroll down does the comment section appear<sup>2</sup>. So how can I find out which event is triggering the comment section to load? And how can I artificially dispatch it? — Otherwise the HTML element for the comment box will be nonexistent.

I've been using `getEventListeners()` to figure out which events work on which elements.

<sub>2: Another example is when a YouTube page reloads/navigates to another one, which is triggered by `yt-navigate-start`.</sub>

---

As you've probably noticed, I'm not a JS expert, so feel free to go down to the basics or give me noob tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can focus on the comment input using its Id:

```js
document.getElementById("simplebox-placeholder").focus();
```

However, it is not loaded until you page-down and wait for it to load. So, page-down and wait a while.

Also, depending on the width of the window, you might need to multiple page-downs.

Comment: I still do think that there should be a way of triggering the "scroll-effect event" programmatically. For example, `getEventListeners(document.querySelector('ytd-item-section-renderer'));` lists several interesting events, like `yt-load-next-continuation`.

Comment: I've manages to `window.scrollBy(0,9999)`, wait, scrollBy again, wait, find the wrapper, `scrollIntoView(false)`, `focus()`, `click()`, `textContent="whatever"`, find the "comment" button - but not to imitate click...  Sheesh!!!
wrapper/box - see edits...

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question to only feature the focusing part, and, thus, your answer will be accepted. I'm gonna ask the loading of the comment sectio on a different question.

Comment: The continuation to this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63875009/4756173) now.