# How to Load the Comment Section Programmatically on YouTube? (Without Scrolling) (JS/HTML/DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, youtube, browser-extension

> I'm creating a [browser extension to enhance YouTube's keyboard navigation](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/youtube_kbd_nav). One of the shortcuts I have in mind is for commenting<sup>1</sup>.

At first, YouTube doesn't load the comment section below a video. Only when you scroll down does the comment section appear<sup>2</sup>. So how can I find out which event is triggering the comment section to load? And how can I artificially dispatch it? — Otherwise the HTML element for the comment box will be nonexistent.

> This question is the continuation of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63862394/4756173).

<sub>1: I'm currently using Dart, but it mimics JS and later gets transpiled to it anyway.</sub> 
<sub>2: For example, when a YouTube page reloads/navigates to another one, the event `yt-navigate-start` is triggered.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on the extension doing that thing too.

(see https://github.com/cyfung1031/Tabview-Youtube)

I finally figure out the solution to programmatically reload it.

There is a set of criteria you need to have to perform the "loading of comments"

> **1. The `ytd-comments#comments` must be in a visible area.**
>
> You can make it `position:absolute` and negative `z-index` to hide in
> the page but still "be visible". You cannot make it `display:none` OR
> `content-visibility:hidden`. Also, it shall have height and width, so
> that its `getBoundingClientRect()` is within the visible area (screen
> view)
>
> **2. Attribute `[hidden]` is set on `ytd-comments#comments`.**
>
> **3. `#continuations` exists and inside the `ytd-comments#comments`.**
>
> The non-zero size block element `#continuations` is the only element
> inside the `ytd-comments#comments` with its own dimension. This is
> used to detect the visiblity of the loading mechanism. It is always at
> the end of the section to perform the triggering.

When you use make scroll, or `window.dispatchEvent(new Event("scroll"));`, the event listener on the `scroll` event in Youtube's coding will detect the visibility and perform the loading.

You must wait Youtube to perpare the stuff for you (i.e. `#continuations`) , and then you can trigger with `ytd-comments#comments`'s attribute `[hidden]` and `window.dispatchEvent(new Event("scroll"));`

After the content is feteched, attribute `[hidden]` will be removed.

You might check my userscript https://greasyfork.org/scripts/428651-tabview-youtube for Youtube Tabview plugin.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get `getBoundingClientRect` to tell me the element "had a size", unfortunately. Tried setting variations of width/height to no avail.

Comment: hello, thanks, for me `ytd-comments#comments` does not even load when the extension script starts